# Docker Private registry - access registry images after container is removed

Tags: docker

I created a private docker registry and successfully pushed and pulled some images.

The thing is, the private registry runs in a container and when I remove the container using

```
sudo docker rm [container name]
```

I realize that all my pushed images are lost after a new container has been created.

Is there a way to keep the images in a private registry even when that private registry container is removed and another created?

Comment: What kind of backend datastore did you configure when running the registry? You have not indicated which registry container you used. The standard one describes in it's example how to configure amazone S3 storage. Other types available. https://github.com/docker/docker-registry

Comment: i used a local datastore.i prefer using a local one.

Comment: Ok then, so why don't you map your registries storage to a mapped filesystem volume so that the containers data is not lost and can be used by another container?

Answer (score 0):

If you start your registry using the `dev` or `local` config (assuming the [default sample config](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/config/config_sample.yml)), you can map the `storage_path` directory to a directory on the host machine using a volume mount `-v`.

Using a modified version of the quick start example:

```
docker run \
    -d --name registry \
    -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=local \
    -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry \
    -v /tmp/registry:/registry \
    -p 5000:5000 \
    registry
```

This will store the registry's data on the host machine in `/tmp/registry`, and persist when the container stops.